# Kalman Filter for particle tracking

Tags: kalman-filters

I am new to Kalman and trying to use it for a particle tracking technique for velocity measurments in Multiphase systems. I have particle locations but there are error associated with these locations. Can use of Kalman Filter be useful in reducing error in this case?

Comment: You can certainly use it.

Comment: Please suggest any book or paper for beginners like me?